# How to set automatically the height and width of UserControl on the value of this control after dragging it?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I create `UserControl` and I have it in Toolbox. When I drag a control onto the main window, the height and width properties are set to 100, not those of the control (for example 70x50). Am I able to change it?

My control:

```
<local:Control x:Class="Controls.Sensor"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Controls"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="70" d:DesignWidth="50"
         x:Name="control">
<Grid >
    <Ellipse Fill="Transparent" Opacity="0.5" Grid.Row="1">
        <Ellipse.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Binding.TargetUpdated" >
                <EventTrigger.Actions>
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard Duration="0:0:1" RepeatBehavior="Forever">
                            <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill.(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
                                <DiscreteColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="{Binding FirstColor, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True}" />
                                <DiscreteColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5" Value="{Binding SecondColor, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True}" />
                            </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger.Actions>
            </EventTrigger>
        </Ellipse.Triggers>
    </Ellipse>
</Grid>
</local:Control>
```

and after drag:

```
<Controls:Sensor HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="100" Margin="728,524,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100"/>
```

when I expected:

```
<Controls:Sensor HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="70" Margin="728,524,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="50"/>
```

Comment: What happens if you set the Width and Height to 100 instead of DesignWidth/Height?

Comment: @Dinac23 the same is happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This very annoying bug in the Visual Studio was already reported in the past. The Visual Studio developers team wasn't going to fix it.

See the following post: [WPF UserControl height always set to 100](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/62538/wpf-usercontrol-height-always-set-to-100.html).

Comment: I can't say it is annoying because setting fixed Width/Height is needed very rare. WPF layouts are based on Panels and Alignments, width/heigth are expected to change

Comment: @ASh: Nonetheless Brian Bergh, who reported this issue on the [**developercommunity.visualstudio.com**](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/62538/wpf-usercontrol-height-always-set-to-100.html), he said that too. And I agree with him. It would be more convenient if after drag/drop was used the width/height set during development. A developer can always click on the `UserControl` and selecting _Layout ► Reset All_ or_ Reset Size_. **After all, this problem exists with other parameters of the `UserControl`, after drag/drop**!